# Generate impulse train in python

Tags: python, pulse

I want to generate a train of impulses. I can generate one impulse by below code:

```
imp = signal.unit_impulse(200, 'mid')
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 200), imp)
```

After I create the impulse train I want to convolve one wavelet to it. For one impulse I can do it like below:

```
imp = signal.unit_impulse(200, 'mid')
points = 200 # number of samples per seconds
a = 22
c = signal.ricker(points, a)
co=np.convolve (imp,c)
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 399), co)
```

But I need to do this for a long period of time. So at first I need a trian of pulses. Then I will convolve the wavelet to the train.
Please give me your idea about this.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use `unit_impulse` to create *multiple* impulses: instead of `'mid'`, simply specify a list containing the locations of the different pulses, for instance:

```
import scipy.signal as signal
imp = signal.unit_impulse(200, [10,40,50])
```

The code above will yield the following figure:

[image]